# Python - How to generate a random number with a bitwise probability?

Tags: python, random, probability

I need to work out the number of atoms decayed in a specified time. I was given the half life of Radon-222 and have calculated from this the probability that any one atom will decay within 1 minute.

If I have x atoms and the probability is y, how do I calculate the number which decay within 1 minute?

I have a very inefficient function at the moment (see below) but this can probably be done much more easily.

```
def Decay(atomno, decayrate):
    out = 0
    for atom in range(atomno):
        if random.uniform(0,1)<decayrate:
            out += 1
    return out
```

Comment: This question belongs on Math.SE ...

Comment: "If I have x atoms and the probability is y, how do I calculate the number which decay within 1 minute?" <- You multiply your number of atoms with the probability you have already worked out for a single atom?!

Comment: My function would not output `int(x*y)` however. I need it to be random, as in real life.

Comment: And sorry for my originally badly worded question. I did look for similar questions but they weren't really what I needed.

Comment: @Rishav   Yes? What are you ...ing for?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a random number from a binomial distribution, as produced by `numpy.random.binomial`.

For a reasonably large number of atoms, this can be approximated by a normal distribution like so:

```
from random import normalvariate

def binomialvariate(n, p):
    """
    Generate random number from a binomial distribution
      using a normal-distribution approximation
    """
    return normalvariate(n * p, (n * p * (1 - p)) ** 0.5)
```

which, used like

```
ATOMS = 1000000
DECAY_PROB = 0.1

for i in range(10):
    print(binomialvariate(ATOMS, DECAY_PROB))
```

gives

```
100307.20222237767
99709.2126851899
99834.51936804672
100085.99501737293
100121.93115561221
100379.9532069239
99848.39057702095
99465.46179311829
100357.77320779095
99990.74240156381
```